# Partitioning data between NULL and non-NULL values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm polling a resource for it's current state and log this info into a table. Sometimes the resource is not available, so the state will be NULL.

I'm trying to partition the data into consecutive blocks of rows, where status is NOT NULL followed by a block of rows where status is NULL. From this partitions i'd like to get more information, like earliest and latest timestamps of these blocks, number of lines of this block and some more.

Example data may look like this

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
 ID INT IDENTITY,
 STATE NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
 TS DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @data
(
 STATE,
 TS
)
VALUES
(N'A', DATEADD(SECOND, 0, GETDATE())),
(N'B', DATEADD(SECOND, 1, GETDATE())),
(NULL, DATEADD(SECOND, 2, GETDATE())),
(NULL, DATEADD(SECOND, 3, GETDATE())),
(NULL, DATEADD(SECOND, 4, GETDATE())),
(N'A', DATEADD(SECOND, 5, GETDATE())),
(N'C', DATEADD(SECOND, 6, GETDATE())),
(N'D', DATEADD(SECOND, 7, GETDATE())),
(N'B', DATEADD(SECOND, 8, GETDATE())),
(NULL, DATEADD(SECOND, 9, GETDATE())),
(NULL, DATEADD(SECOND, 10, GETDATE()))

ID  STATE   TS
1   A       2018-12-13 17:01:38
2   B       2018-12-13 17:01:39
3   NULL    2018-12-13 17:01:40
4   NULL    2018-12-13 17:01:41
5   NULL    2018-12-13 17:01:42
6   A       2018-12-13 17:01:43
7   C       2018-12-13 17:01:44
8   D       2018-12-13 17:01:45
9   B       2018-12-13 17:01:46
10  NULL    2018-12-13 17:01:47
11  NULL    2018-12-13 17:01:48
```

Please note that this is simplified as timestamps may be irregularly (not always 1 sec difference) and that this is reduced to one resource, it's name omitted (in real data there are some resources with name column)

For what I try to get, these data are four partitions, consisting of ID (1, 2) [a block of non-null values], then (2,4,5) [NULL values], then (6, 7, 8, 9) [non-null again] and finally (10, 11)

The minimum TS and the Count for these partitions should be

```
17:01:38    2    non-NULL
17:01:40    3    NULL
17:01:43    4    non-NULL
17:01:47    2    NULL
```

I tried grouping and windowing functions, but both handle all distinct values alike.
Does someone has a solution for this?

SQL-SERVER 2014

Comment: This is a typical `gaps and islands problem`.   Google that term and you will find examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get the gap number and group by it.

```
SELECT min(TS) ts,count(*) cnt,val
FROM (
SELECT *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) - 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN STATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY ID) grp,
 (CASE WHEN STATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'non-NULL' END) val
FROM @data
) t1
GROUP BY grp,val
ORDER BY min(TS)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa3adc2d29b6779ea200abab13b9d79d)